# SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' after deleting all of Nodejs

Tags: node.js, macos, react-native, export, atom-editor

I kept getting lots of different types of errors, so i tried to delete all my nodejs/ node modules files and restart, but now I am getting the following error:

```
/Users/macbook/Coding Practice React Native /food-boilerplate/node_modules/react-navigation/src/index.js:1
export * from '@react-navigation/core';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at [stdin]:8:24
    at Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:133:18)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:310:38)
[Finished in 0.77s]
Press any key
```

I am sure it is a simple fix, but I have no ide what to do and have searched all over the internet for a solution and nothing has worked.

Here is the file I am trying to run and getting this error for:

```
import {createAppContainer, createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation'
/// import {createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack'
import SearchScreen from './src/screens/SearchScreen'

const navigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Search: SearchScreen
  },
  {
  initialRouteName: 'Search',
  defaultNavigationOptions: {
    title: 'Business Search'
    }
  }
)

export default createAppContainer(navigator)
```

and here is index.js:

```
module.exports = {
  get StateUtils() {
    return require('./StateUtils').default;
  },
  get getNavigation() {
    return require('./getNavigation').default;
  },

  // Navigators
  get createNavigator() {
    return require('./navigators/createNavigator').default;
  },
  get NavigationContext() {
    return require('./views/NavigationContext').default;
  },
  get NavigationProvider() {
    return require('./views/NavigationContext').default.Provider;
  },
  get NavigationConsumer() {
    return require('./views/NavigationContext').default.Consumer;
  },
  get createSwitchNavigator() {
    return require('./navigators/createSwitchNavigator').default;
  },

  // Themes
  get ThemeContext() {
    return require('./views/ThemeContext').default;
  },
  get ThemeProvider() {
    return require('./views/ThemeContext').default.Provider;
  },
  get ThemeConsumer() {
    return require('./views/ThemeContext').default.Consumer;
  },
  get ThemeColors() {
    return require('./ThemeColors').default;
  },
  get useTheme() {
    return require('./useTheme').default;
  },

  // Actions
  get NavigationActions() {
    return require('./NavigationActions');
  },
  get StackActions() {
    return require('./routers/StackActions');
  },
  get SwitchActions() {
    return require('./routers/SwitchActions');
  },

  // Routers
  get StackRouter() {
    return require('./routers/StackRouter').default;
  },
  get TabRouter() {
    return require('./routers/TabRouter').default;
  },
  get SwitchRouter() {
    return require('./routers/SwitchRouter').default;
  },

  get createConfigGetter() {
    return require('./routers/createConfigGetter').default;
  },
  get getScreenForRouteName() {
    return require('./routers/getScreenForRouteName').default;
  },
  get validateRouteConfigMap() {
    return require('./routers/validateRouteConfigMap').default;
  },

  // Utils
  get getActiveChildNavigationOptions() {
    return require('./utils/getActiveChildNavigationOptions').default;
  },
  get pathUtils() {
    return require('./routers/pathUtils');
  },

  get SceneView() {
    return require('./views/SceneView').default;
  },

  // SwitchView
  get SwitchView() {
    return require('./views/SwitchView/SwitchView').default;
  },

  // NavigationEvents
  get NavigationEvents() {
    return require('./views/NavigationEvents').default;
  },

  // HOCs
  get withNavigation() {
    return require('./views/withNavigation').default;
  },
  get withNavigationFocus() {
    return require('./views/withNavigationFocus').default;
  },
};
```

Thank you for any help!!!